# ListView get index if contains text

Tags: c#

I've been looking for this whole day, but couldn't find it.
I need to get index of ListViewItem that contains  noncase sensitive string somewhere in it's text.

I know there's FindItemWithText, but it's case sensitive + searches only begining of listviewitem.text

I could iterate through ListView everytime, but I hoped there's a simple solution to this.

Comment: Can you share some code that you've tried already?

Comment: Put your listview items in a Dictionary - use the Dictionary to populate your ListView AND search for whatever text you like, in whatever position, using ~ToLower()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not true that [`ListView.FindItemWithText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3h4x385(v=vs.110).aspx) is case sensitive.

Quote: "The search is case-insensitive."

But you're right. It searches for items that *begin* with this text.

But you can use LINQ. You can use whatever method you need. If you f.e. want to search for the first item which text contains a specific substring you can use:

```
ListViewItem firstMatchingItem = listview1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Text.IndexOf("foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```